# CREATE SCHEMA using a name stored

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, schema

I am trying to create a new schema on my postgres database which name is stored on an existing table, my query look like this:

```
CREATE SCHEMA (SELECT name FROM table)
```

But I am getting a syntax error. What am I doing wrong? Is this a valid way to create the new schema? Which other solution exist for this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not possible, create schema syntax required a valid schema name (i.e. valid schema name string). in your case it will throw exception as

```
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
SQL state: 42601
Character: 15
```

Comment: It's possible with dynamic SQL.

Comment: @xiidarkevil: This answer is not very helpful. You should accept a_horse's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with dynamic sql:

```
do
$$
  declare s_name text;
begin
  -- make sure there is exactly one row in that table!
  -- otherwise you need some where condition or an aggregat to ensure that.
  SELECT name INTO s_name FROM some_table;
  execute 'create schema '|| quote_ident(s_name);
end;
$$
```

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: thanks for fixing the syntax error (too much Oracle lately...)